# Create sequence of additions

Tags: r, sequence, repeat

I want to extract specific rows of my dataframe, following a sequence of rownumbers.

The sequence should be:

```
7, 14, 21, 31, 38, 45, 55, 62, 69.....until 8760.
```

So it always is starting from row 7 and then it goes `+7 +7 +10` and this should be repeated until the end.

I know *rep* and *seq*, but I don't know how to deal with that +10 after the +7. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
x <- rep(c(7, 10), c(2, 1))
out <- cumsum(c(7, rep(x, ceiling(8760 / sum(x)))))
```

Result

```
head(out, 10)
# [1]  7 14 21 31 38 45 55 62 69 79

tail(out)
# [1] 8726 8733 8743 8750 8757 8767
```

If you want `out` to end at `8760` you might do

```
c(out[out < 8760], 8760)
```

Comment: Thx! But this gives me actually +7 +7 +10 +7 +7 +7 +10....its not completely right. I need: [1]  7 14 21 31 38 45 55 62 69 79.....

Comment: @Essi Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rep`

```
x1 <- rep(c(7, 10), c(2, 1))
out <- cumsum(c(7, rep(x1, 8760 %/% sum(x1)))))
out1 <- out[out < 8760]
head(out1, 10)
#[1]  7 14 21 31 38 45 55 62 69 79
tail(out1, 10)
#[1] 8685 8695 8702 8709 8719 8726 8733 8743 8750 8757
```

Comment: Thx! But this gives me actually +7 +7 +10 +7 +7 +7 +10....its not completely right. I need: [1]  7 14 21 31 38 45 55 62 69 79.....